# Loading Multiple SVGs in My React App Distorts Their Colors

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm importing and using them as a ReactComponent each:

```
import { ReactComponent as Avatar1 } from "../assets/avatar1.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Avatar2 } from "../assets/avatar2.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Avatar3 } from "../assets/avatar3.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Avatar4 } from "../assets/avatar4.svg";
```

etc...

and use them like so: (I'm also using MUI in my current project)

```
  <Avatar sx={{ width: "5rem", height: "5rem", margin: "0 auto" }}> //This is a MUI component
    <Avatar1 />
  </Avatar>
```

SVG code of two of the avatars:

https://codepen.io/omaralseddik/pen/RwZOjPb

https://codepen.io/omaralseddik/pen/LYjvOVa

They load just fine when I load only one avatar on the page. Upon loading multiple avatars, however, their colors distort like so:

[First 2 got their colors distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNqgh.png)

[All but the last SVG got their colors distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1PJU.png)

What might be causing this? And how do I fix it?
Please let me know if there's anything more I need to share if the info I provided here is insufficient.

Comment: Look like you have duplicate classnames, thus the last loaded svg styles all previous ones

Comment: Neat! Changing all the classnames manually within every SVG file solved the problem. Thanks a lot, Danny! I wish I could upvote.